# Thread wont start within __init__ method of my class

Tags: python, multithreading

Within the `__init__` of my class I want to trigger a thread that handles a function.
For some reason the thread isnt triggered though, nothing just happens:

```
class OrderBook:

    # Create two sorted lists for bids and asks
    def __init__(self, bids=None, asks=None):
        if asks is None:
            asks = []
        if bids is None:
            bids = []
        self.bids = sortedcontainers.SortedList(bids, key=lambda order: -order.price)
        self.asks = sortedcontainers.SortedList(asks, key=lambda order: order.price)

        # Populate Orderbook with 50 orders
        threading.Thread(target=populate_orderbook(self, 10)).start()
        print(f'Orderbook initialized..')

    ...
```

And the function to be triggered which isnt though

```
def populate_orderbook(orderbook_instance, n):
    order_type = ['Limit']
    side = ['Buy', 'Sell']

    i = 1
    while i < n:
        # Create random order
        order_obj = Order(
            order_type=order_type[0],
            side=random.choice(side),
            price=random.randint(1, 1000),
            power=random.randint(1, 1000),
        )
        orderbook_instance.add(order_obj)
    print(f'Orderbook prepopulated..')
```

Comment: `target` should be a function, not a function call. That's a classic dupe

Comment: You never increase `i` which keeps the thread in an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the target function eagerly, on the main thread.

You have to pass *the function* as an argument to the Thread constructor, and the arguments in separate, so that the function will be called inside the running thread:

```
        threading.Thread(target=populate_orderbook, args=(self, 10)).start()
```